# How do I write a regex that performs multiple substitutions on each line, EXCEPT when the line starts with a certain string?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a regular expression that surrounds "http" URLs with angle brackets, except for lines beginning with two slashes. The best I've come up with is:

`s#^(?!//)(.*?)(http://[^\s]+)#$1<$2>#gm;`

This works great for these two:

---

Input: `http://a.com`

Output: `<http://a.com>`

---

Input: `//http://a.com`

Output: `//http://a.com`

---

However, it fails here:

---

Input: `http://a.com http://b.com`

Actual Output: `<http://a.com> http://b.com`

Desired Output: `<http://a.com> <http://b.com>`

---

Why doesn't my regular expression keep matching? Am I using /g wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rewriting it a little...with my suggestions and using the whitespace modifier so it's actually readable.  :)

```
s{
    (?:^|\G)     # start of the last match, so you never backtrack and don't capture.
    (?!//)       # a section without //
    (.*?)        # followed by anything
    (
        http://  # with http://
        [^\s]+   # and non-spaces - you could also use \S
    )
 }
 {$1<$2>}xmg;
```

Trying this in perl, we get:

```
sub test {
    my ($str, $expect) = @_;
    my $mod = $str;
    $mod =~ s{
            (?:^|\G)       # start of the last match, so you never backtrack.
            (?!//)       # a section without //
            (.*?)        # followed by anything
            (
                http://  # with http://
                [^\s]+   # and non-spaces - you could also use \S
            )
          }
          {$1<$2>}xmg;
    print "Expecting '$expect' got '$mod' - ";
    print $mod eq $expect ? "passed\n" : "failed\n";
}

test("http://foo.com",    "<http://foo.com>");
test("// http://foo.com", "// http://foo.com");
test("foo\nhttp://a.com","foo\n<http://a.com>");

# output is 
# Expecting '<http://foo.com>' got '<http://foo.com>' - passed
# Expecting '// http://foo.com' got '// http://foo.com' - passed
# Expecting 'foo
# <http://a.com>' got 'foo
# <http://a.com>' - passed
```

Edit:  Couple of changes: Added the 'm' modifier to make sure that it matches from the start of a line, and change \G to (^|\G) to make sure it starts looking at the start of the line too.

Comment: That's really really good, and I might be able to figure out the last little problem on my own, but of course any input is appreciated: In practice it also has a /m modifier, since it operates on a big blob of text. This causes it to fail on "foo\nhttp://a.com"

Comment: ...which should return "foo\n<http://a.com>" but actually returns "foo\nhttp://a.com"

Comment: In fact, I'm going to accept your answer anyway, since it's perfect for the question as originally asked.

Comment: Hey, changing your \G to (^|\G) and your $1<2> to $2<3> seems to work!

Comment: ah yeah :)  Figured that one out right as I was updating the question... give me a bit and I'll add it.  :)

Comment: Also, I made the first group a non-capturing group.  That way it's clear to others that you really don't care what the first part is.

Answer (score 4):

You should really use two regexes; one to identify the "commented-out" lines and one to modify the http's in the regular lines.

There might be a non-standard way to combine the two regexes or replace all of your multiple (http...)+ matches, but I wouldn't use them.

Comment: The regex is fed into a legacy function that operates on a big, multi-line blob of text. I wish I could split it into lines and do what you say, but that would require major regression testing.

Comment: Major refactoring and regression testing, I should say.

Comment: @Mike - if you need to match the beginning of multiple lines, consider the 'm' modifier. It causes ^ and $ to match the beginning or end of any line.

Comment: Oh, in practice I do -- somehow that got wiped out when I was turning it into an SO question.

Answer (score 3):

You  can't really do this for an indefinite number of expressions. Try this:

```
s#(http://[^\s]+)#<$1>#g unless m#^//#;
```

This will replace all of the URLs in the line, but only if the first two characters of the line aren't "//". Sure, it's a little more complicated, but it works (I think).

EDIT: My answer is the same as aib's, but I have code.