# Regular expression to capture all groups in a Kleene Plus closure

Tags: python, regex

I run into a problem where I need to capture all groups in a Kleene plus closure.  I tried with another scenario and got the same behavior.  So an example

```
(?:([A-Za-z]+) )+
```

for the string

```
This is a sentence.
```

I always get back the last match as a group instead of all the possible groups.  In the case above, group(1) is `a` and there are no other groups.  I would want group(1) to be `This` group(2) to be `is` and group(3) `a`. For the above I was using `search`

**EDIT**

Serves me right for not using the exact case I care about ...

```
\{([ A-Z]+)(?:\|([ A-Z]+))+\}
```

and

`NBAR -> { AP NBAR | NBAR PP | VPG | N | N N }`

In this case, `findall` does not work.  Using [this online tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/) I get `[(u' AP NBAR ', u' N N ')]` which is quite similar as to what `groups()` would give me.

Comment: Python don't have the \G feature which allow this kind of captures. But you can find alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529830/do-python-regexes-support-something-like-perls-g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", sentence)
```